# tableview duplicate cell went scrolling down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When creating data cells are not overlapped
When i scrolling cell is duplicated and override in other cell, When scrolling over unmarked cells has been overwritten, i don't know how to fixed it

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)    

   let name:UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 110, y: 0, width: 200, height: 25))
        name.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.addSubview(name)

        let imgView:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        imgView.image = UIImage(named:  mangHinhSP[indexPath.row])
        cell.addSubview(imgView)

        let price:UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 110, y: 25, width: 100, height: 20))
        price.text = arrayPrice[indexPath.row]
        price.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        cell.addSubview(price)


        let desc:UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 110, y: 50, width: 250, height: 50))

        desc.text = mangMoTaSP[indexPath.row]
        desc.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.addSubview(desc)
return cell
}
```

Comment: This is because of the way cells are reused as you scroll. When setting up the cell in the `cellForRow` method you must reset or change all the data displayed in it, so that the data from the previous use of the cell does not show instead.

Comment: Also, you are making and adding subviews in this method, but they are probably being added multiple times because this method is called multiple times for any given cell. As the answer by Vadian states, it is better to use a custom cell class which has references to its views and labels etc. Then after dequeuing a cell, cast it to your custom class and then all the subviews can be referenced in the `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: If you find yourself using `addSubview` in `cellForRowAt` then you are doing it wrong. Use custom cells that have the needs views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`..ReusableCell` means what it says: Cells are reused. All views which are added to the cell will remain.

You are responsible to keep the cell in a defined state.

I'd recommend to create a **custom** cell in Interface Builder with all desired UI elements and `IBOutlet`s.